# Python - ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: python

Receiving this error and uncertain why:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
from docx import Document
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\docx-0.2.4-py2.7.egg\docx.py", line 17, in <module>
from lxml import etree
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Previous versions of this question received the answer that the Python and package versions were perhaps not the same, but my Python, lxml and docx versions are 64-bit.

Comment: Can you post your python version? Type python in command prompt and post output of it

Comment: @be_good_do_good "Python 2.7.10 (default, May 23 2015, 09:44:00) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win 32"

Comment: how many python versions are installed? can you tell out of 2 commands? `where python.exe` and `where pip.exe`?

Comment: C:\Python27\python.exe and C:\Python27\Scripts\pip.exe, respectively

Comment: can you try `c:\Python27\python.exe -m pip uninstall docx` and then try `c:\Python27\python.exe -m pip install docx`?